# How do I change the Xcode workspace my project is in?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have read that getting the error 'Linker command failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation)' is because my project is running on the incorrect workspace, it is currently running on .xcodeproj, and I need it to run on .xcworkspace.

How can I change this? Thanks

Comment: you use pods ???

Comment: Share snapshot (directory structure) of your project folder?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yeah, I'm using Firebase so using their pods.

Comment: close .xcodeproj and open .xcworkspace

Comment: @Sh_Khan that's sorted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close .xcodeproj and open .xcworkspace , as you can't access the target of the project if you are opening .xcodeproj while opening  .xcworkspace  at the same time

Answer (score 0):

if you are installed pods for your project then open your project with project name .xcworkspace. Project with this icon from your project folder ([image])

Answer (score 0):

if you have opened multiple projects in xcode then can switch of them  using Command(⌘) + ~